# How to make constant night on Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have minecraft server on Spigot 1.15.2. I want to have always night on one of my worlds.

I tried to do `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false`, but when someone on the server goes to bed, this don't work and it's create a day.

I can't find any plugin to have constant night on my server. \

Is there any possibility? Or is there a way to block players from sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

You can either [shoot them out of bed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/350710/171580) or just have a repeating command block with `/time set night`.